# What does this javascript regular expression do

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this regular expression in some javascript code and not sure exactly what is doing to the string.

```
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var state = History.getState();
var current_url = state.cleanUrl;
var results = regex.exec( current_url );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it replaces `[` with `\[` and `]` with `\]` in name. Then it puts name in a new regex which searches for `\`, `?` or `&` followed by the name variable, followed by `=`, followed by any number of `^`, `&`, or `#` characters.

In the context of a url, it seems it means to find a particular `$_GET` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This regex is used to see if the parameter contained in `name` (ie. `param`  or `param[]`) exists in the url `current_url`.

Examples, for name the regex is:

```
name     regex
----     ----- 
param    [?&]param=[^&#]*
param[]  [?&]param\[\]=[^&#]*
```

The regex will search if there is a `?` or a `#`  followed by `param=`  followed by any number of character that is not `&` or `#` (ie. the value of the param).

Comment: Thanks M42 this is also helpful